Acer no longer recognizes the SSD it came with
I have an Acer Aspire XC-1660G desktop PC. I took its Western Digital PC SN530 NVMe SSD and installed it in a separate computer. On that computer I formatted the drive and installed Windows 10 onto it. On that computer I'm able to boot into Windows 10, no problem. Now when I take that same SSD and re-install it in the Acer, the drive is not recognized anywhere. It doesn't appear in the BIOS nor in the browser when I boot to Windows installation media on a USB drive.
Things I tried:

Installed Intel RST Driver 18.31.2.1034 from the product support page onto a separate drive to load from the Windows installer. Windows reports that no signed drivers were found.

I tried to create a bootable USB drive with the latest BIOS version on the product support page, R01-B0, but the BIOS doesn't recognize it as bootable media.


After the above steps failed I re-installed the SSD into another computer. The other computer recognizes the drive, but I can no longer boot to the drive until I format it and re-install Windows on it. I only have two SSDs and I'm afraid to test my other SSD in the Acer.
How can I get the Acer to recognize the SSD that came with it again?

Simply extracting the "BIOS", actually UEFI, zip file to a FAT32 formatted USB stick should make a bootable media.

Unless the two PC's are identical, then that is unlikely to succeed. During installation on the other PC, drivers it needs were installed, not the ones for the Aspire. Even if you get Windows to start booting, there will likely be issues.

@DrMoishePippik people always tell me that but I've done it many times. I've transferred laptop SSDs to desktops and booted to them without issue. I can still access, format, and partition the drive but can longer boot install Windows to the SSD on my second computer either. I believe there's a problem with the drive. I'll test against a second drive when it arrives.
